# Statically and dynamically linking the same library on Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, dynamic-linking, static-linking

I have a shared object/executable that link both statically and dynamically to the same library .

Library: liba.a and liba.so

> > **liba.a** created using :  ar -rv liba.a a.o  ,
> >      contains **libprint()** --> prints "static5"
> >
> > **liba.so** created using: gcc -shared -o liba.so -Wl,-h,liba.so a.o , contains **libprint()** prints "dynamic5" ,
> >      **libprint2()** prints "dynamic6"

Exe **b** created by linking to both archive and shared object:

<strike>When linking with GCC/Linux, i find that the implementation called is ALWAYS from liba.a .</strike>

I have a function **libprint()** defined in liba.so, liba.a that prints out a different value.
From what i see, this is based on the link order:

> gcc -o b b.o liba.a liba.so -lc
>   ./b
>
> static5
>   dynamic6
>
> gcc -o b b.o liba.so liba.a -lc
>   ./b
>
> dynamic5
>   dynamic6

Why we would intentionally need to link to the .a and .so for the same library?:

How do we get the shared object to take preference over the archive, other than link order?
 ( **-dy** / **-Bdynamic** does not seem to have any effect?)

> > <strike>1. If the shared object is missing, the exe fails with an error</strike>
> >     <strike>2. We can place any dummy shared object with the same name , just to satisfy the dlopen()</strike> 
> >     <strike>3. Even once the shared object is loaded , the function from the archive is called</strike>

**Update #2**
Here is the **actual** problem ( as mentioned in [Statically and dynamically linking the same library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236495/statically-and-dynamically-linking-the-same-library) )

> **libd.so** is linked to shared object **liba.so**
>   ldd libd.so
>   liba.so => ./liba.so
>
> **b** is linked to shared-object **libd.so** and archive **liba.a** .
>
> gcc -o b b.o libd.so liba.a  -lc
>   ldd b
>          libd.so => ./libd.so 
>          liba.so => ./liba.so

Now, **b** seems to call the function from archive first, and then the shared-object.

So , even if we update the **liba.so** , these changes will not reflected in **b** . 
Is there any way around this ?

Comment: might want to add/search tags gcc. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

When you put the .a first, the linker finds `libprint()` in it and links it, but not `libprint2()`. It continues searching the libraries in order to find the other function, and finds it in the .so.

When you put the .so first, both functions are found and linked successfully, hence there's no need to look for them any further.

There should be no reason to link *both* the static and dynamic versions of the same library, since either should provide all functions found in the other.

Comment: Thanks @ignacio-vazquez-abrams. 
I have an executable that is linked to a .a and a .so . I am trying to figure out what possible reason there could be for doing so.

The problem is, we can update the shared object, but it does not seem to get called since the executable still uses the function from the original archive.

Comment: .a files [are linked to at build time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246799/static-library-dynamic-library-confusion/2246911#2246911).

Comment: I have updated the question with the actual case. 

The shared object file comes first in the link line, however, the actual function is present in a linked so file, and not the actual so.
This still causes the archive version to be picked up.